# Why my stackpanel items always aligning to vertical if even i mentioned horizantalmode in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I wrote the below code in my page:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="166" Margin="10,602,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1346" x:Name="thumbnailViewer">
               <ScrollViewer
                x:Name="thumbnailViewerScroller"
                Padding="0"
                BorderThickness="0"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="UserList">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">-->
                                        <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" Tag="{Binding Path=id}" Width="164" Height="150" Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                    <!--</StackPanel>-->
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Inside of the scrollviewer i mentionsed stackpanel and aligning the items as horizontal.But always i am getting the items alignment as vertical while running of the code.Please tell me how to align the items as horizontal?What was wrong in my code why items are aliging to vertical even i mentionsed Orientation="Horizontal in stackpanel.

EDIT:

```
<ScrollViewer
                x:Name="thumbnailViewerScroller"
                Padding="0"
                BorderThickness="0"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >-->
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="UserList">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <!--<DataTemplate>-->
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" Tag="{Binding Path=id}" Width="164" Height="150" Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                <!--</DataTemplate>-->
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
</Scrollviewer>
</Stackpanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the `ItemsControl` instead.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl ...>
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" 
                   Tag="{Binding Path=id}" Width="164" Height="150" 
                   Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"></Image>

         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Getting innerexception while using above statements.Exception: Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.

Comment: @user1237131 did you put something inside the stackpanel? This is not allowed.

Comment: @user1237131 put it in a new question :)